# Ball & Chute Interaction - Ball "sits on top" of chute

Tags: objects, rigid-body-simulation

I'm very new to Blender, and I want to roll a ball down a chute. I stretched out a cube, deleted three of its faces, then smoothed it out to make a trough shape & solidified it. Then I made a cylinder, deleted the face on either edge, and solidified it into a tube. Both are set as passive rigid bodies.

My ball does not recognize the empty space these deletions have created, however. If I try to drop my ball into the chute, [it slides  along an invisible field and doesn't fall through the tube.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/euhwL.jpg) If I try to put the ball "into" the trough instead of dropping it in, [it flies away in a huff.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0a3EE.jpg)

I think you can tell from the gifs what I'm trying to accomplish. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, just figured it out. Chutes needed their rigid body collisions to be set to mesh, not convex hull.